# Using List<string> with Azure Table Storage

Tags: .net, list, azure, azure-storage

I am currently making use of the Windows Azure Table Storage Mechanism, having a class which extends TableEntity. However, one of the fields of this class is a List. When getting the entity back from the table, it is returned as a DynamicTableEntity rather than a normal Table Entity. Is there a way to obtain the list from the table rather than serializing the list and storing it on a blob?

Comment: Sorry I left one detail out, the list is a List<string>, which is supposed to be supported by the Azure Table Storage. Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As you may already know, complex data types are not natively supported by Azure Table Storage. For a list of supported data types, please see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179338.aspx.

One option is to serialize this List into a delimited string as you mentioned.

Other option is to use a 3rd party library like Lucifure Stash (http://lucifurestash.codeplex.com/). I haven't used it myself but the documentation states that you could store arrays and lists as entity in Azure Tables.